# Ошибка при запуске в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java

При запуске любой программы высвечивается ошибка (на скрине). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто как мысль - таки прочитать что вам написала идея, найти тот самый файл и поглядеть что в нем не так? Ну или переставить идею?

Comment: Скорее всего пользователь у Вас назван кириллицей.

Comment: "Пупсик" - хм... неплохо, но лучше было бы латиницей. Не любит идея русские буквы (как и многие другие программы кстати). Она не может получить доступ к файлу `config/options` из-за этого. Тут есть два пути - менять расположение папки конфигурации (если интересно - пинганите меня, распишу в ответе) или переименовать пользователя. Советую второй вариант, сам так сделал и жить стало гораздо удобнее  (правда я систему переустановил, но это уже другая история)

Comment: @Стас, спасибо за ответ. Но если брать 1 вариант, то куда необходимо менять расположение папки конфигурации?

Comment: @Александр расположите её где угодно, где в пути не будет кириллических символов. Например, `C:\IdeaConfig` вполне подойдёт.

Comment: @Стас, сделал все как вы сказали, перенес config в папку IdeaConfig (предварительно создал на диске C), но ничего не изменилось, даже ошибка пишется та же самая

Answer (score 0):

> Перенес config в папку IdeaConfig (предварительно создал на диске C), но ничего не изменилось

Вам недостаточно перенести папку в другое место. Нужно изменять конфигурацию `IDEA`.

- Открываете файл: `path/to/idea/bin/idea.properties`
- Вам нужны пункты `idea.config.path` и `idea.system.path`
  Уберите от них комментарии и установите путь, в котором не будет кириллических символов. (Требуется использовать прямые слеши)
- Желательно также изменить `idea.plugins.path` и `idea.log.path`
- Сохраняете файл и перезапускаете `IDEA`

---

P.S

Это может решить не все ваши проблемы (у меня, например, после этих действий заработала отладка, но режим `Run with coverage` так и не запустился).

Так что лучше использовать имя пользователя на латинице.

Comment: спасибо большое, я попробую. Но вообще данная проблема не должна быть связана с кириллицей и именем в целом. Я пишу на idea уже полгода с таким именем, и все работало.